# One user with two format in send email action in sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a problem in sharepoint designer 2013, when I want to use the “`send email`” action, in select user window. I have two entries for one user! One in this format: “`DomainName\Username`”, and one of in this format: “`i: 0#.w|DomainName\username`”.

Only when I select the second format, send email works correctly! Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a pure SharePoint login functionality, your environment uses "Domain/ User name" format to login in to your system.

When you integrate any third party login i.e configure FBA, SharePoint changes the format of AD users to "i: 0#.w|DomainName\username". Even if you remove your FBA, your login users has same identity further.

"i: 0 #." is used to identify the type of claim you have set up in your environment. You can get more information [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spidentity/2010/01/26/belated-intro-to-identity-in-sharepoint-2010/).

Comment: thanks love thakker,
if you mean my problem happened because of Configure FBA, I have mentioned problem only in one site collection, although I configure FBA  for our farm, other site collections don’t have this problem for user’s authentication!